# Is GAE Stateless? What are the implications?

Tags: google-app-engine, stateless

I was once told that GAE is stateless.  I understand the concept of statelessness in general but I could use some guidance in conceptually applying it to a GAE-type-system.

I'm asking this question specifically because I an app I've developed appears to be having an interference problem.  That is, when two or more people use it at the same time, it becomes confused.  (I am continuing to bugtest to confirm that the error only occurs during simultaneous use.) I perceive that there are two ways such interference could theoretically occur: A, incorrect GQL queries getting the wrong db records(I checked this, nope); or b. at the server level.  My question: is the latter actually possible?  When the app is serving, can one user interfere with another by, say, changing the state of a variable within the program?  Or, perhaps, is this prevented by statelessness?  I am confused and may have misstated the question.  Namaste.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose without more details. Can you show us some code that reproduces the problem? In your comments on Rick's answer you mention you're using global variables like 'userData'. You can't do that, because a) Multiple users will use the same instance of your app, and b) The same user will use multiple instances of your app.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're confusing a few terms. First off, what language are you using? Is this java or python?

The person who told you that GAE is 'stateless' doesn't know what they are talking about, or else you are confused as to what they told you. GAE is a web server platform and the statefulness of your app is up to you. HTTP is a stateless protocol (and GAE is for building web applications which use http) but you can absolutely turn on sessions and achieve statefulness for users that way.

The error condition you are describing is one of concurrency. You have shared resources in GAE (the datastore, memcache, etc) and you also have eventual consistency in the datastore if you are using the High-replication datastore.

GAE does not guarantee that the same server instance will serve multiple requests by the same person, and by default there is no multi-threading (in java anyway, I'm not sure about python). With no multi-threading there will only be 1 person on any instance at any given time. However, if you enable multi-threading you must make sure that your code is thread-safe, or else you can have 2 users modifying a variable on a single instance, but this is not unique to GAE.

You can definitely have 2 users modifying the same datastore entity on 2 different servers or the same memcache entry and you need to code for that case by using transactions, etc. Also with eventual consistency there can be a lag between a write and a read so if you write data and another user immediately reads it they might not get the same value
 back.

Comment: I am using Python, high replication.  I will investigate multithreading, but I didn't enable any such option.  I doubt that my users are modifying the same datastore entry, because every datastore entry contains a userId column and users may only access / modify their own records.  but it is definitely possible that I'm doing so with the Memcache (which I don't understand well).  My python global objects are named things like `userData`. Perhaps they are overwriting each other, and I need to name them something like `user.userId.userData` to avoid conflict?

Comment: If you are using memcache you need to consider all of that data to be shared and two users can definitely overwrite the values.

Answer (score 5):

GAE still runs (virtual?) servers to handle HTTP requests.  A server instance may start up, handle a number of requests, and shut down.  At any given moment, a large number of server instances may all be running.  Two sequential HTTP requests may end up being served by the same server instance or separate server instances.  You need to design your software to be stateless, because you have no idea which server instance it runs on.

However, since GAE still runs virtual servers, it's possible that you can set some sort of global static variable that can be modified and accessed between multiple HTTP requests on a given server instance.  Most likely you've done something along the lines of this.

This state is generally useless, because, as mentioned, you have no guarantees  that subsequent HTTP requests will hit the same server instance, or any control on when a server instance is shut down.  However, for example, if you wanted to run an experiment on how many requests each server instance serves on average, you probably could do that.

Comment: You're getting me close to what I need to understand.  Please elaborate: each user will send many HTTP requests per usage session.  If each user is not handled by a consistent (virtual) server, how are variable states saved?  For instance, I create a python object of the class `userData()` - how and where is that stored, if the server instance keeps changing?

Comment: If userData is an arbitrary python class, then it's just instantiated on the server instance that's running.  Depending on the scope of the variable, it may or may not live through multiple requests.  Either case, you don't want to use this.  You want to store the data in the datastore, so userData SHOULD be derived from ndb.Models, and you can store it in the datastore.  The datastore is shared between all server instances, so data fetched from the datastore will be "global".  You do need to use transactions to synchronize datastore accesses though.

Comment: Oh, and if you're using memcache, you need to be aware that memcache data can be cleared at any time.  As the name suggests it's a cache, you need a stable backing data, like the datastore, to store your data in case it's not available in memcache.

Comment: Having trouble.  I am using the datastore to store all my user data, but what you're saying sounds like it means I need to do a DB read every single time a user loads a page, if I want reliable access to their data.  Is that true?  At this point I am not using the memchache (I read up on it, and nowhere have I used memcache.anything).  What I don't understand is that every time a user loads a page, I check their ID and reload their data from the datastore if it has changed.  Thus, how am I getting concurrency problems?

Comment: @cognitiveUpgrade Yes, you need to read the user's data from memcache or the datastore on every request. If you're already doing that, what are your global variables for?

Comment: You do need to fetch from the DB on every user access, unless you use memcache, as you described.  It sounds like you're doing it right.  You'll have to post some code on how you're reading/writing the data in order to tell whether there are concurrency issues.  You'll also have to describe the concurrency issues you're dealing with.

Answer (score 3):

A few remarks on "statelessness":

1. HTTP protocol in itself is stateless, i.e. requests do not depend on each other (= do not need to be called in some predefined order).
2. Web applications are usually statefull. They achieve this by saving data and enforcing/limiting certain actions based on that data, e.g. a user login.
3. Data can be saved on web servers in numerous ways: database, cache, memory. One standard way for for saving user data/state are [servlet sessions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagm.html).
4. When people say that App Engine is stateless they usually refer to the fact that frontend instances do not have their own permanent storage (i.e. a writable filesystem). To save state code on frontend instances must use one of Google APIs: datastore, memcache, etc..

Comment: Thanks.  I think my issue was not understanding the nature of the memcache.  I'll update this question once I've solved the issue.